# socket.io on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have an express node server running that is a backend for a REST API and a Websockets (for chatting feature) while my client is React.js

When I deploy my server to an AWS EC2 instance with security groups set up, I am able to make http api calls, but my socket.io connection doesn't work. I have tested the server locally on my localhost, which works.

I think this does something with the proxy in the package.json because testing locally when I change the proxy to my EC2 instance public ip while keeping my socket.io connection connected to my localhost it does not work.

I am not getting any "connection refused" errors.

**So my question is how does the react.js proxy effect the socket.io connection?**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?